# how do i get google sheet UI

Tags: google-sheets-api

I was able to get sheet data like this
[image]

to get this result I wrote this

```
public class CreateSheetServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");`

        Sheets service = GoogleAPITestServlet.getSheetService();

        Spreadsheet sheet = new Spreadsheet();
        sheet.setSpreadsheetId("testSheet");
        SpreadsheetProperties props = new SpreadsheetProperties();
        props.setTitle("샘플 시트");
        props.setLocale("ko_KR");
        sheet.setProperties(props);

        OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
        service.spreadsheets().create(sheet).executeAndDownloadTo(os);
    }
}
```

than,I really want know how I get sheet UI like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to display the sheet on an external website, you can [embed your Google Sheet on a webpage](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/zfgPF5l2rec).

Otherwise, if you're looking for some way to display and edit data from OUTSIDE Google Sheets, then you can't.

Unless you implement the entire spreadsheet webapp from scratch, your only option is to use Google's UI. You can, however, have a somewhat Google Sheets "instance" (on their servers too) if you have Google for Work.

Comment: thanks your answer. I dont care about UI, I just wanna display sheet UI having data having data like pic I post

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve :( Do you simply want to know how to display that JSON in an HTML table? Do you want to find some way to put that JSON data *into the Google Sheet*? Perhaps you could try to explain more clearly.

Comment: If you're having trouble explaining it in English, explain it in your native language. I'll try looking for someone/something to decipher it.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English. Simply I want to display UI like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5fYQ.png

Comment: I can create that spread sheet and I can see that as jason data, but I cant see that sheet as spread sheet UI

Comment: You mean you're having trouble accessing http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/... ?

Comment: yeah actually I feel diffilculty to access  docs.google.com/spreadsheets